# Threading to connect to different servers has unpredicatble outcome

Tags: c, multithreading, networking, pthreads

I have two servers running at the specified ports.

I am trying to connect to both of them parallelly using threads.

The code works as desired when I'm not threading.

```
int main(){
    // Server 1
    char* ip1[]={"127.0.0.1","42069"};
    // Server 2
    char* ip2[]={"127.0.0.1","42070"};

    file_l *file = create_file_l("file.txt",ROOT);
    if(file->size != 0)
        return -1;
    // Common Data Structure that is sent to both threads to prevent overwriting
    file_n *filen = create_file_n(file);
    filen->part_size = 1024*1024*16;

    add_seed(ip1, filen);
    add_seed(ip2, filen);
    return 1;
}
```

The `add_seed` function connects to a given server and creates a new thread to handle data from that server.

```
int add_seed(char* ip[], file_n* n){
    // Connects to given address and goes file descriptor
    int cfd = connectTo(ip);
    if(cfd==-1)return -1;

    // Data Structure Used to pass parameters to both threads
    conn_det *cd  = malloc(sizeof *cd);
    cd->socket = cfd;cd->file = n;
    // Thread Creation
    pthread_t temp;
    pthread_create(&temp,NULL,initiate_data_transfer,cd);
    pthread_detach(temp);
    return 1;
}
```

The `initiate_data_transfer` function sends data requests and handles incoming response from the server.

```
void* initiate_data_transfer(void *ptr){
    printf("Thread ID : %ld\n",syscall(SYS_gettid));
    conn_det *cd = ptr;
    file_n *n = cd->file;
    int socket = cd->socket;int rv=-1;
    long size = check_if_available(socket, n->local->name);
    printf("Recv Size : %ld Thread ID : %ld\n",size,syscall(SYS_gettid));

    // Checks if file size has been set by some other thread
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(n->mutex));
        if(n->local->size == 0){           // If not , assign file_size
            n->local->size = size;
            initialize_file_n(n);
        }else{
            if(n->local->size != size){    // If yes and size from this server does not match, then exit.
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&(n->mutex));
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(n->mutex));
    // Data Transfer Part.
    printf("Size : %ld Thread ID : %ld\n",n->local->size,syscall(SYS_gettid));
    while((rv=get_part(n)) != -1){
        printf("Handling Part : %d Thread ID : %ld\n",rv,syscall(SYS_gettid));
        send_fetch_request(socket,n,rv);
        recv_fetch_response(socket,n,rv);
    }

    close(socket);
}
```

The Data Structures used to pass information to the threads.

```
typedef struct File_information_Network{
    long part_size;
    long total_parts;
    int* parts_recieved;
    file_l *local;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
}file_n;

typedef struct Connection_Details
{
    int socket;
    file_n *file;
}conn_det;
```

The problem is that only one of the thread reaches the `initiate_data_transfer` function most of the time.

This can be seen from the fact that `printf("Thread ID : %ld\n", syscall(SYS_gettid));` , which is the first line of `initiate_data_transfer` runs once in most of the cases whereas I've created two threads.

Consider the following logs:

The terminal of Client:

```
user@machine:~/Desktop/cn/FileShare/path$ ./a.out 
Connected to: 127.0.0.1
Thread ID : 3164
Connected to: 127.0.0.1
user@machine:~/path$ ./a.out 
Connected to: 127.0.0.1
Thread ID : 3169
Connected to: 127.0.0.1
user@machine:~/path$ ./a.out 
Connected to: 127.0.0.1
Thread ID : 3174
Connected to: 127.0.0.1
user@machine:~/path$ ./a.out 
Connected to: 127.0.0.1
Thread ID : 3179
Connected to: 127.0.0.1
Thread ID : 3180
```

I don't know what's going wrong and using `printf` to debug is not helping me figure that out at all. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the main thread simply exits before the both threads could reach `initiate_data_transfer` and do work.

Although you have detached the newly created threads, the return from `main` thread will still exit the process.

So instead of:

```
return 1;
```

from `main`, do:

```
pthread_exit(0);
```

And that'll let the threads carry on. When the last thread exits, the process will automatically exit.

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks.